# How to have both docker and apache using only one port?

Tags: apache, docker

I have apache using port 80 and the server is only accessible from outside at port 80 due to firewall. If I run a command like the following, there will be a conflict at port 80. Could anybody show me how to support both application at the same port (two domains are mapped to the same IP, so they can be presumably separated by the domain name)? Thanks.

```
docker run -d -p 80:8787 quay.io/hemberg-group/scrna-seq-course-rstudio
```

Comment: Do you want to access docker from outside of the host system or just insdie?

Answer (score 1):

Run the docker with  `-p 80:8787` will try to listen a Physical machine. and also the `Apache` listen the `80` by default.

You can't run more than one programmer to listen the same `PORT`, but if you just want to a map `80` which you open to the public to the backend server, you can use a `Nginx` as your delegation server. and then you can run number of servers.

Here is simple config of your `Nginx`

```
server { # php/fastcgi
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    access_log   logs/domain1.access.log  main;
    root         html;

    location ~ \ {
      server   127.0.0.1:8787;
      server   127.0.0.1:8788;
      server   127.0.0.1:8780;
    }
}
```

And your container can run as following way:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 quay.io/hemberg-group/scrna-seq-course-rstudio
docker run -d -p 8788:8787 quay.io/hemberg-group/scrna-seq-course-rstudio
```

And your `Apache` server can be configuration with another `PORT`, example `8780`